# Array_agg alterantive - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgreSQL version 8.3.4, which doesn't support the function "array_agg"

my definitions for the tables are:

```
create table photos (id integer, user_id integer, primary key (id, user_id)); 

create table tags (photo_id integer, user_id integer, info text, primary key (user_id, photo_id, info));
```

I came across this query, which gives me what I need:

```
    SELECT photo_id
   FROM   tags t
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING (SELECT count(*) >= 1
           FROM  (
              SELECT photo_id
              FROM   tags
              WHERE  info = ANY(array_agg(t.info))
              AND    photo_id <> t.photo_id
              GROUP  BY photo_id
              HAVING count(*) >= 1 
              ) t1
           )
```

but I can't use it because of my version.
Is there any alternative query to this one that I can use?

Comment: Postgres 8.3 has been out of support for nearly three years now. You should upgrade to a current version rather than trying to find workarounds with such an old versio.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's not up to me.

Comment: post ddl for both tables?..

Comment: Do you mean the create tables definitions? posted.

Comment: yes, I meant it. But I don't see how your query would  work now :) that alias "t" is for joining tags against tags?..

Comment: Whoever it's up to needs a firm kick in the unmentionables. Will they wait until they can't get hardware that'll run an OS that'll still run 8.3 and then upgrade, 15-20 years from now? Or wrap it in an emulator and keep going, with ever growing costs and complexities? It's absurd not to have an upgrade path, and that's way, way too long to leave it.

Comment: @VaoTsun, take a look at the query now please.

Comment: @CraigRinger the upvote is from me. I agree, but still, there is nothing I can do about it, mate.

Comment: Thanks again. I can't solve it in any other way, if you have a workarond you are welcome to help.

Comment: is it a special way of joining, that you do here? Can you rephrase it in words? like "same tags for different photos" or so? :)

Comment: I am trying to return all the photos that have at least k other photos with at least j common tags.
here k = j = 1

Comment: `select 
 distinct t2.photo_id
from tags t1
join tags t2 on t1.info = t2.info and t1.photo_id <> t2.photo_id 
` does it work for k=j=1 ?..

Comment: It works, can you generalise it for any k, j?

Comment: `select 
 t2.photo_id, count(*)
from tags t1
join tags t2 on t1.info = t2.info and t1.photo_id <> t2.photo_id 
group by t2.photo_id
` does second column stand for your wanted k?..

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer from your silence I assume you found what you were looking for? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  t2.photo_id, count(*) 
from tags t1 
join tags t2 on t1.info = t2.info and t1.photo_id <> t2.photo_id 
group by t2.photo_id
;
```

and `HAVING count = k` if you want the exact k